# Dockerized project cannot connect to elastic

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, nlog

I have a docker compose file containing elasticsearch and my project. When I tried to start the project, elasticsearch couldn't register, I didn't know where I was doing wrong, can you help?

the codes i wrote
https://github.com/bayramerenn/LogingInfra

nlog.Development.config

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true">
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"></add>
</extensions>
<targets>
    <target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
        <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch" 
                uri="${configsetting:item=ElasticUrl}" 
                index="Development"/>
    </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" ></logger>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" ></logger>
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="database" ></logger>-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="elastic" ></logger>
</rules>
```

nlog.Production.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"></add>
    </extensions>
    <targets>
        <target name="elastic" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" flushTimeout="5000">
            <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
                    uri="${configsetting:item=ElasticUrl}"
                    index="Production"/>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="elastic" ></logger>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ElasticUrl": "http://localhost:9200/"
}
```

appsettings.Production.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ElasticUrl": "http://elasticsearch:9200/"
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_volume:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - nlognet
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.2
    container_name: kibana
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200/
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200/
    networks:
      - nlognet
  nlog.api:
    image: nlog_api
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NLogElastic/Dockerfile
    container_name: nlog.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    ports:
      - "5005:80"
    networks:
      - nlognet

volumes:
  elasticsearch_volume:

networks:
  nlognet:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: What does *couldn't register* mean? Do you see an error? What error? Are you able to connect to elastic when you start the app on the host? Are you able to connect if you hardcode ElasticUrl in nlog config? Please find the exact problem (docker compose configuration, nlog configuration, aspnet configuration, etc) you have rather than just saying "my app doesn't work"

Comment: How do you want me to explain it, it's pretty clear I don't get any error there is a problem with the connection if you want to help the code is there

Comment: Start with app running on the host which connects to elastic running in docker via a hardcoded url. Then add moving parts until you find what is broken

Comment: Elastic logs give a publish ip, it connects when I give it, but isn't it ridiculous to check it all the time?